# Undefined offset notice because of array definition in php

Tags: php, arrays

I try to define an array, but although having read all of the suggestion here, I still got an error notice when execute.

My form consist among everything else, field min which define the number of textareas in

```
<input type="text" name="min[1]">
```

**My PHP file has:**

```
<?php
$min = $_POST['min'];
$area = array();

for($j=1; $j=<$length; $j++) {
if($_POST['row'][$j] != "") {

    if(($_POST['min'][$j])!="") {
    for($k=1;$k<=$min[$j];$k++) {
    $area[$j] .= '<textarea name="label'.$j.$k.'" rows="3"' ></textarea>';
    }}
    if(($_POST['min'][$j])=="") {
    $area[$j] = '<textarea name="label'.$j.$k.'" rows="3"'" ></textarea>';
    }
    $blah .= $j.') '.$row[$j].'<br/>'.$area[$j].'<div id="inner'.$j.'"></div><br/><br/>';
}}
```

I can see that the problem is in array, because the script try to locate the keys which are not there. So how to defne this in advance... This works but it's no solution as you can se:

```
$area = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",);
```

Comment: Your code isn't syntactically valid. It should be clear from coloration of this post itself.

Comment: It is pretty easy. Al of the variables, or actually all of the $_POST methods are called on the simple input text fields. SO, min and row are actually input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if that array element exists before you check its value.

Change

```
if(($_POST['min'][$j])!="") {
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['min'][$j]) && $_POST['min'][$j])!="") {
```

Comment: Actually didn't work in my case. The problem is in array $area. Because it is not defined by $_POST['min']. It should be defined somehow in the loop, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

`$length` is not initialized...

In PHP the first array index is 0.

You could iterate through array with the `foreach` operator.

If you copy `$_POST['min']`  in `$min` , use it. stop using `$_POST['min'`] it's confusing.

Comment: @user3244442 There is probably other problems with your code.